# How to fetch email id from LinkedIn android?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

How do I fetch the `email` address from *LinkedIn* profile in my Android app?

Comment: If the user has the linkedin app on the device then they use the email as the unique id so you might be able to dig it from the AccountManager in that case.. but the question is missing a bit of info, are you using a LinkedIn SDK ?

Answer (score 10):

You need to set scope with email permission. After that you will be able to recover that specific data.

```
private static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.W_SHARE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS);
}
```

Then use following URL to make GET request.

```
String url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,public-profile-url,picture-url,email-address,picture-urls::(original))";
```

With this scope your **ApiResponse** will retrieve user's email.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the API documentation?  From what I can see, there is no way to get the email ID from their API.  My guess is that LinkedIn protects this particular information (as they should).  If they allowed my personal information to be retrieved by anyone with access to the API I would likely get a lot more spam then I do.

I don't think you can access this information.

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/people